# Win8/JS - Detect Snapped view then change CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I just read over the Win8 app development requirements and saw that it NEEDS to be able to snap.

So, is there an easy way to detect if it's snapped and then change the CSS file? Could you help?

I need it to detect if the width is 320px (The width of a snapped pane) and also SCREEN_WIDTH-320px (The width when an app is snapped next to it)

Has anyone done this? Could you provide some code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a CSS media query:

```
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: fullscreen-landscape) {
}

@media screen and (-ms-view-state: filled) {
}

@media screen and (-ms-view-state: snapped) {
}

@media screen and (-ms-view-state: fullscreen-portrait) {
}
```